# R: Delete rows based on particular word(s) from multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

The questions seems repeat but I have searched thoroughly and I couldn't find the answer. So here is my query:

I have to delete rows in a dataframe when a user gives certain type of keywords. My data look like below where `source` and `target` are the column names.

```
  source target
1   mike   john
2   john    ram
3  shyam   mike
4   mike   mike
5    rat    cat
6  mouse    dog
7   mike    cat
8    cat   mike
```

Now, if I give "mike" as the word then all the rows with "mike" as a keyword should be deleted irrespective of the column it belongs. The following should also work if I give two or three words like "mike" & "cat" etc.

Comment: Can you please share data and not screenshots?

Comment: Shared the data also!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rowSums`

```
keyword <- "mike"
df1[!rowSums(df1==keyword),]
#  source target
#2   john    ram
#5    rat    cat
#6  mouse    dog
```

If the keyword has multiple elements, use `%in%` with `lapply`

```
keywords <-  c("mike", "cat")
df1[!Reduce(`|`,lapply(df1, `%in%`, keywords)),]
#  source target
#2   john    ram
#6  mouse    dog
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(source= c("mike", "john", "shyam", 
"mike", "rat", "mouse", "mike", "cat"), 
target = c("john", "ram", "mike", "mike", "cat", "dog", 
"cat", "mike"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but it seems to be not working. I am trying to remove "mike" if it appears only in 1 column also. Thanks

Comment: @RahulAgarwal  I used the example you showed as `image` (updated in the post now) and it is working for me.  BTW, if your columns are `factor`, convert it to `character`

Comment: Thanks. This works fine. Just one more thing, can you suggest a solution which works irrespective of number of words I give. I am asking this because I am passing these words to dataframe by UI (R shiny). So, user can sometimes give just one word and sometimes multiple words at a go

Comment: @RahulAgarwal  THe second solution works irrespective of the number of words

Answer (score 2):

In one custom function using `apply()` in combination with `all()`:

```
custom.subset <- function(df, keywords) {
                y <- df[apply(df, 1, function(x) all(!x %in% keywords)),]
        return(y)
}

#Test it
keywords <- c("mike","cat")
custom.subset(df1, keywords)
#  source target
#2   john    ram
#6  mouse    dog

keywords <- c("mike")
custom.subset(df1, keywords)
#  source target
#2   john    ram
#5    rat    cat
#6  mouse    dog
```

Comment: It is working fine if I give only one word. Although if I use it like this:
keywords <-  c("mike", "cat")
df1[apply(df1, 1, function(x) all(x != keywords)),]. 
The solution is not working!!

Comment: Thanks. This works fine. Just one more thing, can you suggest a solution which works irrespective of number of words I give. I am asking this because I am passing these words to dataframe by UI (R shiny). So, user can sometimes give one word and sometimes multiple words at a go.